# jquery image gallery fadeIn & fadeOut problems

Tags: jquery, gallery, fadein, fadeout

I have done a very simple gallery using:

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
$('#mainimg img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});
```

but when i add the fadein + fadeout either the images disappeared when a thumbnail is clicked or the same image fades out then back in so im sure im nearly there but need pointing in the right direction...how do i get the previous image to fadeout and the newly clicked image to fadein please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` uses `opacity`, so you image just become 'invisible'.

If you need fadeout and fade in you can use callback function to set opacity back.

```
$('*').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).css({
        'opacity' : 1,
        'display' : 'block'
    });
});
```

Or just put a `fadeIn()` on `fadeOut()`, I think the second is better:

```
$('*').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
```

You should change you code in this way:

```
/**
 * binding 'click' event I would advice you to use not .click(function(e) {}) but .live('click', function(e) {});
 * difference is that, if you load via AJAX, or construct another element by javascript, and append it to the DOM
 * your trigger wouldn't work, because it's runs binding only on page load, and if the page changes
 * it wouldn't bind trigger to the new elements, how does this .live('click', function(e) {});
 */
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){ 
    var img = $(this); // storing image, that was clicked
    $('#mainimg img').fadeOut('slow', function() { // fading out mainframe image
        // linking the callback function on when the main image if faded out
        $(this).attr('src', img.attr('src').replace('thumb','large')); // when image is already invisible, changing the source of the image
        $(this).fadeIn('slow'); // fade in mainframe image again
    });
});
```

If I get you right, that cause Main image to fade out, change source, and while fade in loading big image as a src.

Comment: im relatively new to jQuery could you show me an example using my code but obviously modified? I'm still unsure as to where to put them...thanks

Comment: the way you have shown makes so much sense..i'm sure when i try things in jQuery I over complicate them! I'm at work now so i'll try this later and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: unfortunately this does what it was doing with me... changes to the new picture which THEN fadesout and then fades back in.. :(

Comment: Thats cracked it!! you are an absolute star. Thanks very much

Comment: could you explain the code a little to me? no problem if you dont have the time :)

Answer (score 0):

You ve should wait untill image is loaded and only then fadeIn the new one.

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){

  //fade out here

  var img = new Image(),
      src = $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large');

  img.load = function(){

    //End animation on container if necessary
    $('#mainimg img').attr('src', src);
    //Start fadeIn

  }

  $(img).attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't get where is the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

devdRew's idea of using callbacks is one option.  You can also chain settimeout calls to kick off a series of events once a person clicks on the image and sequence them the way you want.

Comment: could you explain the code a little to me? no problem if you dont have the time :)

Comment: I see that you have accepted an answer.  Did it work or are you still looking for help?